# Covert varchar(150) to datetime in sql workbench

Tags: mysql, datetime, casting, type-conversion, mysql-workbench

I have a column with values '2015-02-14 12:23 AM' declared as varchar(150), I tried using to_date, convert and cast but not able to change the format. I would need this to filter on specific month/year/day. Thanks for the help

PS: Mysql instance is running on RDS through amazon AWS - not sure if its relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest storing dates on proper date data type.

to_date is an Oracle function.

In MySQL, you can use [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to converts a string to date then use [Date_format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to give the format you need

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dt,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p'),'%m/%Y/%d') 
from test;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=99e7db25fa8a3565f9716b76c53b5a50)

You can use substring with concat without the need of converting to date format:

```
select concat(substring(dt,6,2),'/', substring(dt,1,4),'/',substring(dt,9,2)) as my_date
from test;
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=eaa0bb177bcff622367e407d00bbe727)

Comment: thank you, this helps. Is there any way that to extract AM/PM from the original field - once I use '%p' time is changing to 24 Hour format. For my analysis I would want to be able to see the day/night usage

Comment: It's better to store the values in a `datetime` column. Then use [DATE_FORMAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to change the *display* of the values however you wish in queries.

Comment: @nareshvadlamudi yes `SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(dt,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p'),'%m/%Y/%d %h:%i %p') from test;` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9ad26bbefaee415a11f0e470ed3d734f

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT CAST( SUBSTRING_INDEX( '2015-02-14 12:23 AM', 
                              ' ', 
                              2
                              ) 
             AS DATETIME
             )
```

returns the datetime value. If you need to use this value in datetime context then you may remove CAST, it will be performed implicitly:

```sql
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF ( MINUTE,
                       SUBSTRING_INDEX( '2015-02-14 12:23 AM', 
                                        ' ', 
                                        2
                                        ),
                       '2015-02-14 12:34'
                       )
```